# How can I display images on a web page via SugarCRM 7 API

Tags: html, image, sugarcrm

I am trying to dynamically retrieve images from Sugar CRM to display on a website. When I am logged in, the images display alright. When I am logged out, I am also denied access to the images hence the wider public will not see the images.

How can I ensure that a logged in header is sent on the webpage without exposing my username and password? Or how can I display the image on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something like this earlier in the year. I can't provide all of the code, but my idea was to create a separate [Entry Point](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Entry_Points/02_Creating_Custom_Entry_Points/) that did not require authorization. From that Entry Point file I essentially spoofed authentication and called the normal download.php Entry Point. It went something like this (keep in mind this code was invoked by hitting `index.php?module=MyModule&entryPoint=MyEntryPoint`)

```
unset($_REQUEST);
$_REQUEST['entryPoint'] = 'download';
$_REQUEST['id'] = $focus->$field;
$_REQUEST['type'] = 'SugarFieldImage';
$_REQUEST['isTempFile'] = '1';
$_SESSION['authenticated_user_id'] = '1';
require_once('download.php');
```

One caveat I found there was that I needed to check first for an existing session before setting `$_SESSION['authenticated_user_id']`, otherwise an actual Sugar user who used the website would go back to Sugar and find that his/her session had been escalated to an Admin account(!). So, I added a check before setting it that way, and code to re-set it back to the original value. Something like this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['authenticated_user_id'])){
    $old_session_id = $_SESSION['authenticated_user_id'];
}
$_SESSION['authenticated_user_id'] = '1';

require_once('download.php');

if(isset($old_session_id)){
    $_SESSION['authenticated_user_id'] = $old_session_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have one question however, what is the download.php for in this instance?

Comment: download.php is the file and entry point for downloading images and documents from Sugar.